# Issue on clicking dates on react Fullcalendar in mobile phone

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

In Mobile devices i am experiencing a delay in pressing like we need to press and hold to select a date in mobile devices, In pc i can select the date with a normal click. I've set selectLongPressDelay to null but still i am facing the issue.My calendar version is "@fullcalendar/react": "^6.1.5",v

```
          <FullCalendar
          plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
          // headerToolbar={{
          //   left: 'prev,next today',
          //   center: 'title',
          //   right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay',
          // }}
          // selectAllow={handleSelectAllow}
          selectLongPressDelay={null}
          // selectLongPressDelay={isMobile ? 0 : null}
          initialView="dayGridMonth"
          editable={false}
          selectable={true}
          showNonCurrentDates={false}
          selectMirror={true}
          events={allEvents}
          select={handleDateClick}
          eventContent={renderEventContent}
          eventDidMount={eventDidMount}
          eventWillUnmount={eventWillUnmount}
        />
```

Comment: If you set the value to null I suspect it will go back to using the default of 1000 (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/longPressDelay). Have you tried setting it to 0?